# Moving GameObjects via script smoothly across the screen like an animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am trying to move GameObjects to different places on the screen, I want them to move like an animation, smoothly moving over while the programming is running. I am using Unity with Leapmotion

I have tried the code below but this just moves the object into the new position immediately, it doesn't move it slowly so that the user can see it move from current location to new. - like an animation.

```
    myobject.transform.Translate(0f,0.5f,1f);
```

Your help will be appriciated. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must either use `Time.deltaTime` in `Update` or `Time.fixedDeltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`

e.g.

```
myobject.transform.position += (direction * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

`transform.Translate` will continue moving an object in the direction provided

What you are looking for is `Vector3.Lerp`

```
obj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(obj.transform.position, new Vector3(0f, 0.5f, 0f), Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to move GameObject, but instead of specifying the destination point, the motion vector is used:

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    ChangeDirection(new Vector3(1,1,0));
}

void ChangeDirection(Vector3 dir)
{
    rb.velocity = dir;
}
```

Don't forget to add a Rigidbody component on object.